# picking wrong column value from txt file unix

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, sh

I am new to scripting, i have following issue:
1. after getting "file:" value in text file its should skip 2 line and then read from 2nd line

(--here i want to skip 2 line if i found "File :" in txt file. that is possible that it occur more then 1 time).

i/p file is:

```
file : noki lab:3232 date : 12/3/16
field length position  text 
name   16 0     1      account name
info   1       10      Bank account info
city   3  0    13      bank acc city name
state  4       17      acc state
```

--here i want to skip 2 line i found "File :" in txt file. that is possible that it occur more then 1 time.

2. after reading i want to pick "filed" and "position" column data only.
   code:

   awk -F ' ' '{print $1,$3}' ip.txt

but i am getting o/p like:

```
name 0
info 10
city 0
state 17
```

which is wrong ,i need output:

```
name 1
info 10
city 13
state 17
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk '/^file :/ {c=2} 
       !(c&&c--) {print $1, $(NF-1)}' file

name 1
info 10
city 13
state 17
```

**Explanation**
when the pattern matches set the counter to two, skip specified number of lines and from the rest print the first and the penultimate fields.

**UPDATE**
if the last column includes white space, the easiest (`gawk` only)

```
$ awk '/^file :/ {c=2}
       !(c&&c--) {print $1,gensub(/.* ([0-9]+)  .*/,"\\1",1)}' file
name 1
info 10
city 13
state 17
```

otherwise, spend time to fix format of the input file.  Get rid of the extra `0` in between fields, change field delimiter to tab etc.

Comment: Looks good. I was thinking of finding a shell tool that would allow me to index from the end, but couldn't think of an easy way to do it.

awk is obviously awesome, but doesn't scale. Then again, for things like this it is quite powerful :)

Comment: Thanks! forgot this handy tool naturally exists.

Comment: Thank you so much its look good but it get failed when text files have below data then it pick wrong data because  it have space in between :  data like:   Rec ID or bank acc no